# passing params from pending intent

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I need to send parameters when the user clicks on the notification.

My Code for create Notification:

```
        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) c.getSystemService(c.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Smartdrifter", System.currentTimeMillis());  

        Intent WA = new Intent(c, WebActivity.class);

        WA.putExtra("url", urlTarget);
        WA.putExtra("valid", notifId);
        WA.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, WA, 0);

        notifManager.cancel(notifId);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(c, titulo, texto, teste());  

        notifManager.notify(notifId, note);
```

My Code for request params:

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

But response is NULL.

There is another form of the request parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! urlTarget is a String and notifId is Long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inbuilt method: `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` in your activity `WebActivity` to catch the pending intent.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    setIntent(intent);
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

}
```